# How to delete all unpublished post in Sitefinity?

Tags: sitefinity

I have 100s of blog posts in unpublished status. What is the best way to delete all unpublished blog posts in Sitefinity? I am in version 9.1.6100.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple widget that deletes all unpublished blog posts using the Sitefinity API as shown here:

http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-delete-blog-posts#deleting-all-blog-posts

Just make sure you add a Where clause for the blob post status being unpublished.

Then add the widget to a temp page and execute the delete logic.

Then remove the temp page.